# How do I take multiple CSS files with the exact same selectors and force one to be used only on a specific div?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a website that uses jQuery UI (and specifically, the jQuery UI themes) for styling.  I have added the Infragistics Ignite UI grid control to this website.  The Ignite grid does not look very good using the jQuery UI theme that I have chosen, but looks really good using the default theme provided with the grid.

Unfortunately, the grid theme also uses the jQuery UI theme selectors, so I have a problem.  I have two CSS files that define the exact same selectors.  One I want to apply to the entire page.  The other I want to apply only to specific divs (i.e. a div that wraps the Ignite grid).

Is there a simple way to force a CSS file to only apply to a single HTML element?  For now, I've put `div.ig` in front of all the selectors in the Ignite style sheet, but that is error-prone busy work that needs to be redone everytime an update is applied, so I don't really like that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing that without modifying one of the jQuery UI themes.

Here's I think the simplest way of modifying the Ignite file at each update:

- strip the file from comments (thus the minified file is OK)
- search "`}`" and replace by "`} .ig(space)`" (without the quotes of course)
- add "`.ig(space)`" at the beginning of the file, remove it at the end
- done, each selector begins with a parent `.ig`

It works only if there are no at-media rule and their double closing braces (and beware of @import, @charset and @font-face at the beginning, just in case)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using LESS so that I could put `.ig { // contents of Ignite CSS file }` and have it transformed into valid CSS for me.

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSS file you want to ignore into the CSS you want to use.

Inside **use_me.css**, write at top

```
@import url("ignoreme.css");
```

This will override all CSS styles in `ignoreme.css` in that clashes with `useme.css`

#### EDIT

This will work only if selectors in both files have same specificity.

[**+ specificity**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: The selectors in both files are identical (they both have `.ui-widget` as an example).  I want file A's `.ui-widget` to apply to the entire page, but file B's `.ui-widget` to only apply to a specific div, without having to modify every selector in file A or file B.

Comment: Well, it depends on what elements you want to be styled from `B`, are they all same elements, have a common class? Or even a set of classes? If there is any pattern to match, there might be a way. If its totally random, then I don't think this is possible.